# Boost.MultiIndex spatial operations

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I needed a spatial map for an application. I found Boost.MultiIndex.
I followed its [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html) and understood how to create a type:

```
typedef boost::multi_index_container<MapNode,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_non_unique<member<MapNode, int, &MapNode::X>>,
        ordered_non_unique<member<MapNode, int, &MapNode::Y>>
    >
> Map_T;
```

And how to insert to it:

```
Map.insert(Node);
```

How do I retrieve a value based on its `x` and `y` coordinates? and how do I check if there is a value there?

Comment: `Boost.MultiIndex` might not be the right container for this. With `Boost.MultiIndex` you can get a view of nodes sorted by `x`, or nodes sorted by `y`, but you cannot find a node at a particular `x` and `y` (without a linear search through one of the views). `Boost.MultiArray` may be better suited to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need boost::multi_index to solve this problem. Simply overload operator< for your type MapNode and use std::set (resp. std::map if multiple nodes with identical coordinates can occur). Therby, operater< compares (e.g.) for x-values first. Iff they are equal, proceed comparing the y coordinate.

There is only one reason for using boost::multi_index: If different access methodes are required. For instance, if you want an additional "view" where the nodes are first sorted by y and than by x too.
However, the member approach of multi_index (as in your code above) is not a good idea. Use identity twice, but provide two different comparison functions. Details can be found in the boost docu.

Finally, all these approches may not be the best possible ones - depending on your application. Specialized data structures are e.g. described in the book "Computational geometry" by Berg et. al.
Unfortunaetlly, I do not know any free implementation of these algorithms...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did it already using hashmap with multiply by prime hash function